# add event to displayed objects in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i've made a small class in JS and i would when i draw id with the "draw" method, add an event like onclick.

There is my JS class :

```
 function Variable(index, value, name, typeVar, x ,y ,position, elseTree) {
        this.type = 0;
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
        this.typeVar = typeVar;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.position = position;
        this.elseTree = elseTree;

        this.draw = function() {
            $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "var"+index).addClass("w3-red item").html('<b>'+name+':'+value+'</b>').css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : y, "left" : x}).appendTo($("#content"));
            variables.push(this);
        }
    }
```

i've tried this but this isn't work (the item is draw but the event not work) :

```
function Variable(index, value, name, typeVar, x ,y ,position, elseTree) {
    this.type = 0;
    this.index = index;
    this.value = value;
    this.name = name;
    this.typeVar = typeVar;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.position = position;
    this.elseTree = elseTree;

    this.draw = function() {
        $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "var"+index).addClass("w3-red item").html('<b>'+name+':'+value+'</b>').css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : y, "left" : x}).appendTo($("#content"));
        variables.push(this);
    }

    $("#var"+index).click(function() {
        alert(name);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not written the code calling `Variable()` but you are probably calling `draw()` to create the element after the click listener. You should use [the 'on' event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to listen the click on your dynamically created element, or put the listener in your `draw()` function as below :

```
this.draw = function() {
    $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "var"+index).addClass("w3-red item").html('<b>'+name+':'+value+'</b>').css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : y, "left" : x}).appendTo($("#content"));
    variables.push(this);

     $("#var"+index).click(function() {
         alert(name);
     });
}
```

Extra tip : As you are using jQuery you can create your element like this instead of using vanillaJS : `$('<div />')...appendTo()`

Edit : Even better, without using concatenation to find your element according to its id :

```
this.draw = function() {
    $('<div />')
       .attr("id", "var"+index)
       .addClass("w3-red-item")
       .html('<b>'+name+':'+value+'</b>')
       .css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : y, "left" : x})
       .click(myFunction)  // Put here the name of the function doing the job you expect instead of 'mFunction'
       .appendTo($("#content"));
    variables.push(this);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for tips and your solution works perfectly ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You are adding  element dynamically.So you need event delegation for this to work.

```
$("#content").on('click',"#var"+index,function() {
        alert(name);
    });
```

OR

```
$(document).on('click',"#var"+index,function() {
        alert(name);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is something like this, just after you created the element:

```
this.draw = function() {
    $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "var"+index).addClass("w3-red item").html('<b>'+name+':'+value+'</b>').css({"position" : "absolute", "top" : y, "left" : x}).appendTo($("#content"));
    $("#var"+index).on( "click", function(){ myFunction(); });
    variables.push(this);
}
```